# Laravel Model event not firing

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-8, jobs

The `Notifications` table has `status` column which stores `boolean` value. i wanted to update the `status` column to true when the job in the queue has run successfully. Doing `dd()` in listener shows output but the column is not updating in db. Can someone help on this?? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

**Job**

```
class SendEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
   public function handle()
    {
      Notification::send($this->user, new courseAddedNotification($this->msg));
      JobFailStatus::dispatch($this->user);
    }
}
```

**Event**

```
class JobFailStatus
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $obj;
    
    public function __construct($status)
    {
        $this->obj = $status;
    } 
}
```

**Listener**

```
use App\Models\Notifications;
class SendStatus
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(JobFailStatus $event)
    {
       //dd($event->obj->status);
        Notifications::updating([
            'status'=>'true'
        ]);  
    }
}
```

`dd(Notifications::all());` in listener handle() gives the below data

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection^ {#1572
  #items: array:6 [
    0 => App\Models\Notifications^ {#1569
      #table: "notifications"
      #fillable: array:6 [
        0 => "notificationTypesId"
        1 => "notificationTypeName"
        2 => "userId"
        3 => "email"
        4 => "status"
        5 => "recipientName"
      ]
      #connection: "pgsql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:9 [
        "id" => 55
        "notificationTypesId" => 1
        "notificationTypeName" => "course Added"
        "userId" => 1
        "email" => "merlin.g@flotillatechs.com"
        "recipientName" => "chris"
        "status" => false
        "created_at" => "2021-08-17 12:25:32"
        "updated_at" => "2021-08-26 17:21:00"
      ]
      #original: array:9 [
        "id" => 55
        "notificationTypesId" => 1
        "notificationTypeName" => "course Added"
        "userId" => 1
        "email" => "merlin.g@flotillatechs.com"
        "recipientName" => "chris"
        "status" => false
        "created_at" => "2021-08-17 12:25:32"
        "updated_at" => "2021-08-26 17:21:00"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #enableLoggingModelsEvents: true
      #oldAttributes: []
    }
```

Comment: `updating` should be `update`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti but how? `update` is not a model event, Right? And `update` shows syntax error `non static method update should not called statically`

Comment: you are right, you cannot call `update` directly, you should have the notification (related to the user) somewhere, like `$this->obj->notifications()->update(['status' => true]);` but that only would work if you only have `1` notification, else it is going to update all notifications (and also, if you have `notifications` as a relation inside your `User` model).

Comment: @matiaslauriti i don't want to update all the rows in `notfications` table, i wanted to update the `status` column only in the present job to `true`.the dispatched `job` has a `status` field in it.  Can u tell me ow can i achieve that?

Comment: @matiaslauriti i've given like `$event->obj->update(['status'=>true]);` , that shows the error `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist`

Comment: I cannot help you with that, you are manipulating a Collection instead of a User, so `$this->user` is a collection not a model...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd have loved to use the comment to clarifying your issues but I cannot because of my rep. So I'm answering based on what I can see and hopefully you can provide some feedback.

First off, I'm assuming this is your own Notification model and not laravel's default notifications.

Now from your SendEmailJob, you seem to be dispatching
JobFailStatus with a user object.
Then in your event, you are passing to the construct a variable called status this would still work don't get me wrong just pointing your naming convention just in case you have some mixup there.

Now after assigning the $status(which is a user object) to your $obj, on your listener, its not being used and you are not updating the notifications model.

Ideally, what you might want to do is this

**Listener**
use App\Models\Notifications;
class SendStatus
{
public function __construct()
{
//
}

```
    public function handle(JobFailStatus $event)
    {
       //dd($event->obj->status);
        Notification::where('userId', $event->obj->id)
           ->update([ 'status' => true ]);
    }
}
```

You can do this instead for better naming and [model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding), assuming you have a user model as well.

**Event**

```
use App\Models\User;
class JobFailStatus
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    } 
}
```

**Listener**

```
use App\Models\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class SendStatus
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(JobFailStatus $event)
    {
        Notification::where('userId', $event->user->id)
           ->update([ 'status' => true ]);

        // or

        DB::table('notifications')->where('userId', $event->user->id)
           ->update([ 'status' => true ]);
    }
}
```

Read more about this on [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent)